# Pourquoi est-ce que « importe » et « mort » rimaient?

Tags: prononciation, poésie

Il y a un poème de Paul Verlaine, [*Vers sans rimes*](https://www.bonjourpoesie.fr/lesgrandsclassiques/poemes/paul_verlaine/vers_sans_rimes), où toutes les rimes sont des rimes pour l'oreille mais pas pour l'oeil.

La dernière strophe est:

> De mourir le premier ou le dernier. Qu'importe,
> Si l'on doit, ô mon Dieu, se revoir à jamais ?
> Qu'importe la pendule et notre vie, ô Mort ?
> Ce n'est plus nous que l'ennui de tant vivre effraye !

Il me semble que Verlaine a dû vouloir qu'on prononce « mort » comme « morte », afin qu'il rime avec « qu'importe ». Mais quelle règle de la prononciation française permettait ça?

(Selon les règles traditionnelles de la poésie française, les rimes devaient être à la fois pour l'oreille et pour l'oeil. Les mots se terminant par une consonne muette riment pour l'oeil seulement si les consonnes muettes sont pareilles. Par exemple, « mort »  rime avec « sort »  et « nord »  mais pas avec « dors »  ou « l'or » .)

Comment: La dernière strophe du poème, contrairemennt aux précédentes, n'a pas de rime (d'où le titre ?). En poésie, les rimes se définissent exclusivement par l'identité des sons. Ainsi les 2 "vers" suivants *Dans la cour du couvent* et  *On voit des poules qui couvent* ne riment pas.

Comment: Je ne crois pas que cette rime fonctionne trés bien. Difficile de faire rimer "mort" avec "importe" ni pour l'oeil, ni pour l'oreille.

Comment: @Frank: D'accord; ce n'est pas une bonne rime dans la langue d'aujourd'hui. Mais dans la langue informelle du dix-neuviéme siècle?

Comment: The translation of "read" in English  ("[transitive] + speech", to have something written on it; to be written in a particular way) is not "lire"; there is no such acceptation of the verb "lire" in French.

Comment: @PeterShor Même au dix-neuvième siècle - je ne suis pas un spécialiste, mais: 1. la langue du dix-neuvième n'est pas trés éloignée de la langue moderne ; 2. pour faire rimer "mort" avec "importe", "mort" passerait au féminin, ce qui me paraît improbable, 3. un poète du calibre de Verlaine ne laisserait probablement pas un tel "détail" au hasard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Je vais tenter de répondre mais je ne suis pas expert et il me manque sans doute des connaissances importantes.

Les mots « importe » et « mort » n'ont jamais rimé en français. Pour qu'ils riment, il faudrait que le « e caduc » soit déjà muet, mais que le T final de « mort » ne le soit pas encore. Or le [e caduc](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_caduc#Histoire) a très longtemps été une syllabe non accentuée, mais prononcée tout de même. Notamment, chez [François Villon](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ois_Villon), au 15<sup>e</sup> siècle, il y a bien une distinction nette entre [rimes féminines et masculines](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rime_en_fran%C3%A7ais#Distinction_entre_rimes_f%C3%A9minines_et_masculines) (avec ou sans un e caduc après la dernière consonne), mais « mort » rime avec « mord » :

> Je suys pécheur, je le sçay bien;
> Pourtant Dieu ne veult pas ma mort,
> Mais convertisse et vive en bien;
> Mieulx tout autre que péché mord,
> Soye vraye voulenté ou enhort,
> Dieu voit, et sa miséricorde,
> Se conscience me remord,
> Par sa grace pardon m'accorde.

(*[Grant Testament* de François Villon](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Le_Grand_Testament), XIV.) Chaque strophe suit le schéma ABABBCBC : « mort », « mord », « enhort » et « remord » riment entre eux, mais pas avec « miséricorde » et « m'accorde ».

Les autres rimes du poème correspondent bien à des rimes au sens courant, c'est-à-dire qu'ils se terminent par la même suite de sons (au moins la dernière voyelle, sans compter un éventuel e caduc, et les éventuelles consonnes suivantes). C'est le cas en français d'aujourd'hui et je crois que c'est le cas du français de Verlaine. Mais **les règles des rimes en poésie française ne se limitent pas aux sons**. Dans la poésie classique française, on fait des distinctions qui sont inspirées de l'étymologie, mais ne correspondent pas réellement à une prononciation ancienne, et sont codifiées par l'orthographe : on parle quelquefois de « rime pour l'œil » qui vient s'ajouter à la « rime pour l'oreille ». Notamment, un S final casse la rime, même s'il n'influence pas la prononciation. Donc « plume/fûmes », « argent/gens », « affaires/sévère », « tic-tacs/trac », « jamais/effraye » ne sont pas des rimes. Le duo « qu'importe/Mort » est le seul où la prononciation est différente, mais aucune des terminaisons de vers n'est une rime formelle. D'où le titre du poème.

Dans *[Vers sans rimes](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Chair/Vers_sans_rimes)*, comme dans *[Vers en assonances](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Chair/Vers_en_assonances)*, Verlaine casse volontairement les règles qui définissent les rimes. Il s'affranchit des règles qui contraignent les rimes au-delà de la prononciation, et va plus loin en faisant rimer des prononciations différentes (« qu'importe/Mort », « monde/rond », « reprend/rendre », « dénonce/*nunc* », « glorifier/fière »).

Ces poèmes se placent dans le contexte d'un débat dans les cercles littéraires sur la légitimité d'une poésie qui s'affranchit plus ou moins des règles traditionnelles, allant d'un relâchement des rimes formelles au vers libres. Je ne sais pas où se place Verlaine dans ce débat, et c'est certainement important pour comprendre ce qu'il a voulu exprimer.

Comment: Alors ils ne rimaient pas. Je suis un peu deçu.

Comment: @PeterShor Pas forçément - Verlaine laisse un petit défaut de temps en temps pour s'affranchir de la tyrannie de la rime. Peut-être pour s'éloigner du _Parnasse_. C'est sans doute un trop grand rapprochement, mais cela me rappelle un peu la notion de _wabi-sabi_ dans l'esthétique japonaise.

Comment: @PeterShor And you can find plenty of perfect rimes and verses in many other 19th century French poets - there is no shortage.

Comment: @Frank: And even the vast majority of Verlaine's poetry has perfect rhyme and meter. I was assuming that Verlaine was anticipating the more modern form of rhymed poetry, where only the sound matters. But apparently that's not quite what he was doing.

Comment: @PeterShor A provocative thought, somewhat contradicting what I was saying about Verlaine completely mastering his art: is it possible that sometimes a poet like Verlaine would get tired of working hard at making verses and just produce a somewhat inferior verse/rhyme?

Comment: @Frank: You may be right. Towards the end of his life, Verlaine was in dire need of money, and I believe the consensus is that he wrote many inferior poems (mixed in with a few good ones) to make a few francs. Both of these poems seem to have been published posthumously.

Answer (score 4):

Réponse brève : *importe* et *mort* ne riment pas.  [*Vers sans rimes*](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Chair/Vers_sans_rimes) reflète un des éléments de la conception de l'art poétique de Verlaine.

**La rime chez Verlaine**
Pour analyser la forme des poèmes de Verlaine il faut se rappeler qu'il avait sa propre conception de l'art poétique et qu'il a expérimenté. Dans son poème l'*[Art poétique](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Jadis_et_nagu%C3%A8re_(1884)/Art_po%C3%A9tique)* il énonce certaines de ses conceptions de l'art poétique tout en les mettant en oeuvre. Voici ce qu'en dit Michel Esnault, créateur du site [Verlaine](http://verlaineexplique.free.fr/index.html) dans l'[étude](http://verlaineexplique.free.fr/jadisetn/artpoete.html) qu'il fait de ce poème :

> Si Verlaine conserve la rime, il ne la place pas au dessus de tout. Si la rime est, pour lui, une parure nécessaire dont on ne peut se passer, on ne doit pas en abuser. Il affaiblit son effet d'écho trop répétitif par des assonances et des allitérations qui répartissent les échos phoniques à l'intérieur des vers.

**Les rimes dans *Vers sans rimes***
On trouve une analyse plus précise de [*Vers sans rimes*](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Chair/Vers_sans_rimes) dans l'article de Florent Albrecht, spécialiste de poésie française du XIV<sup>e</sup> siècle, : [*Verlaine l’anti-théoricien : contre la poétique, la musique ?*](https://www.revue-silene.com/images/30/extrait_140.pdf) paru dans la revue [Silène](http://www.revue-silene.com/f/index.php) :

> Deux des ultimes poèmes tirés de *Chair*, qui s’enchaînent d’ailleurs l’un l’autre dans le recueil, s’intitulent « Vers en assonances » puis « Vers sans rimes ». Tous deux se ressemblent en ce que le premier, un ensemble de cinq quatrains d’octosyllabes, est composé globalement de fausses rimes, alors que le second, trois quatrains d’alexandrins, use des mêmes procédés, tout **en forçant la rime à sauter définitivement en fin de texte<sup>1</sup>**. Le sujet de ces deux textes, insignifiant, montre qu’il s’agit ici d’un exercice de style – de rhétorique ?

> Qu’est ce qu’une fausse rime ? Une non-correspondance entre graphies (cœur/s’épeure ; d’argent/argent ; jamais/effraye), entre pluriel et singulier (plume/fûmes), terminaisons féminines et masculines (normales/mal). Là où les fins de vers offrent une lecture plus complexe, c’est au moment où l’on bascule dans un système, les deux textes offrent de ce point de vue une progression patente, où il n’est question ni d’assonances, ni de fausses rimes, ni de non-rimes, mais véritablement d’une situation limite dépendante de la situation d’énonciation (dénonce/nunc ; jamais/effraye [la graphie y rend-elle nécessaire une prononciation [ei] ?]). S’il n’y a, selon le poète, ni régime assonantique, ni rimes, il y a pourtant une volonté évidente de pointer un fait poétique dans cette **déreliction progressive de la rime<sup>1</sup>** au sein des deux textes : volonté d’ironiser sur les vers-libristes, sur le système peu souple de la rime française ou bien simplement sur la nécessité de rimer, de plier le langage aux règles poétiques au risque de ne plus comprendre la structure du poème ?
> Ces deux textes dénotent, dans la réalité, l’extrême conscience d’un poète dans le déploiement et l’utilisation des ressources de la poésie, ce qu’il faut faire, ce qu’on ne peut pas faire, ce qui peut-être fait ; l’intérêt ne réside pas tant dans notre connaissance de la finalité de ces poèmes que dans notre reconnaissance de la profonde acuité verlainienne sur son art.

<sup><sup>1</sup> C'est moi qui souligne.</sup>

---

Comment: Je ne suis pas du tout convaicu par l'analyse d'Albrecht. Je la trouve à la limite de la caricature d'un dissertant verbeux vide de sens qu'un scientifique pourrait faire. Sur les questions quant à la volonté du poète, il faudrait examiner le contexte historique : ce serait bien là le travail d'un professionnel de l'étude littéraire ! Conclusion à la gloire du poète : ce n'est qu'une affirmation péremptoire de l'analyste. Sur le fond, il n'y a pas de progression dans la déreliction : toutes les « fausses rimes » sont des oppositions singulier-pluriel sauf celle en question.